# Is it possible to execute Multi-line javascript code in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium IDE and trying to record my manual test cases into it.

I want to clear browser cache and browser cookies before I start executing test case.

I want to achieve this with the help of `Execute Script` command of Selenium IDE.

I have tried to search the examples with multi-line JavaScript executed in Selenium IDE but did not get anything.

Please help me on this and let me know if I can execute multi-line code which gives me power to do many things Selenium IDE